# Increasing Premium Items at Re-Tail in Animal Crossing: New Leaf

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

One of my villagers mentioned that you can get Re-Tail to buy more than one item at premium prices if you get streetpasses - but I've been unable to get this to happen.

I regularly get streetpasses and I've tried checking

- when I've gotten a non-AC streetpass before loading the game for the day
- checking the board/shop after having gotten a non-AC streetpass
- when I've gotten an AC streetpass before loading the game for the day
- checking the board/shop after having gotten an AC streetpass

but there's never more than one item being bought at the premium price. What am I doing wrong?

**update**

I still have the night-owl ordinance in effect - and I have never had the bell-boom ordinance in effect. A few days ago, I received a few streetpasses - no more than normal - and had three premium items listed.

Comment: Are you getting New Leaf streetpasses or just regular ones? Maybe you need a certain number of HHA showcase houses? This is the first I am hearing of this.

Comment: Sorry, New Leaf and regular ones. I'll edit to make that clear.

Comment: As far as HHA showcase houses, I've got somewhere in the neighborhood of 20.

Comment: Interesting. If you hadn't heard it from a villager I would just write it off as a rumor. Maybe somebody will know something.

Comment: I know I'm currently up to two premium items a day, and I've gotten exactly one StreetPass since purchasing the game.

Comment: @Fluttershy do you happen to have any ordinances in effect?

Comment: @phantom42 I had Night Owl in effect when it hit 2 premium items. I've since changed to to the Bell Boom ordinance, and that didn't change the number of premium items.

Comment: @Fluttershy thanks. I saw one post implying that the bell boom ordinance was required, or that it increased the number of items. Guess that's been disproved.

Comment: @Fluttershy Do you have any roundabout estimate of how much money you have sold at Re-tail or how often you have sold premium items there? Maybe it's a certain value threshold or sell a premium item x days (in a row)

Comment: @Reafexus If I had to guess, I'd say roughly 2 million bells worth sold at my Re-tail, of which maybe 200k was from premium items.

Comment: So, I switched *away* from the Bell Boom ordinance and was taken from 2 premium items to only 1 premium item.

Comment: I have Bell Boom and at least 1-3 streetpasses a day... still only 2 premium items for me too.

Answer (score 3):

[From the animal crossing wiki](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Re-Tail):

> The small chalkboard sign outside of the store will list at least one premium item each day. If the player sells that item back to the store, Reese will pay double the resell value. There is usually only one item on the board unless the Wealthy Town Ordinance is enacted, or if several people have been tagged through StreetPass.

It would appear that Fluttershy probably has the wealthy town ordinance. <strike>As for having a lot of streetpass people, I can't find a real number online, but if you have about 20, i'm thinking its either 25 or 50...</strike>

found another link with more info about the streetpasses. It's not how many you streetpass, it's who you streetpass and when: [Look at the fourth post down.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/66567835)

If you streetpass someone, you gain their premium item for the day.

Comment: I have well over 25 unique streetpasses (and over 100 total) and I still only have one item, or two with an ordinance.

Comment: edited the question with streetpass data

Comment: @fluttershy also mentioned that they had the night owl ordinance in effect when they initially bumped up to two items. It would make sense that the wealthy town ordinance plays at least *some* part in it, but there seems to be more to it than just that.

Comment: They could've had a streetpass that day. This is all the info the wiki has on it.

Comment: I get Animal Crossing streetpasses daily - with the Night owl ordinance in effect. I have never had more than one premium item a day. I've confirmed that my wife (one of my daily streetpasses) does not have the same premium item as I do.

Comment: It could just have a chance to appear too. Like, if you streetpass, its a 50% chance or something. It'd be nice if Nintendo had a website that explained more of this stuff in detail

Answer (score 0):

You don't gain their premium for the day. You gain 1 new item if you tag between 5 and 10. You gain a second item if you tag 10 and 20. You gain a third item between 20 and 30. You gain a 4th for 30 or more tags in a day. There is a maximum of 5 items that Re-Tail will pay a premium for, even if you get 1,000 New Leaf tags in a single day.